# Mule 4.4 DataWeave append counter to file

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I am reading in a file (see below). The example file has 13 rows.

```
A|doe|chemistry|100|A|
B|shea|maths|90|A|
C|baba|physics|80|B|
D|doe|chemistry|100|A|
E|shea|maths|90|A|
F|baba|physics|80|B|
G|doe|chemistry|100|A|
H|shea|maths|90|A|
I|baba|physics|80|B|
J|doe|chemistry|100|A|
K|shea|maths|90|A|
L|baba|physics|80|B|
M|doe|chemistry|100|A|
```

Then iterating over these rows using a for each ( batch size 5 ) and then calling a REST API
Depending on REST API response ( success or failure ) I am writing payloads to respective success / error files.

I have mocked the called API such that first batch of 5 records will fail and rest of the files will succeed.

While writing to success / error files am using the following transformation :

```
output application/csv quoteValues=true,header=false,separator="|"
---
payload
```

All of this works fine.
Success log file:

```
"F"|"baba"|"physics"|"80"|"B"
"G"|"doe"|"chemistry"|"100"|"A"
"H"|"shea"|"maths"|"90"|"A"
"I"|"baba"|"physics"|"80"|"B"
"J"|"doe"|"chemistry"|"100"|"A"
"K"|"shea"|"maths"|"90"|"A"
"L"|"baba"|"physics"|"80"|"B"
"M"|"doe"|"chemistry"|"100"|"A"
```

Error log file:

```
"A"|"doe"|"chemistry"|"100"|"A"
"B"|"shea"|"maths"|"90"|"A"
"C"|"baba"|"physics"|"80"|"B"
"D"|"doe"|"chemistry"|"100"|"A"
"E"|"shea"|"maths"|"90"|"A"
```

Now what I want to do is append the row/line number to each of these files so when this goes to production , whoever is monitoring these files can easily understand and correlate with the original file .
So as an example in case of error log file ( the first batch failed which is rows 1 to 5 ) I want to append these numbers to each of the rows:

```
"1"|"A"|"doe"|"chemistry"|"100"|"A"
"2"|"B"|"shea"|"maths"|"90"|"A"
"3"|"C"|"baba"|"physics"|"80"|"B"
"4"|"D"|"doe"|"chemistry"|"100"|"A"
"5"|"E"|"shea"|"maths"|"90"|"A"
```

Not sure what I should write in DataWeave to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the ForEach scope, you have access to the counter `vars.counter` (or whatever name you've chosen since it's configurable).
You will need to iterate over each chunk of records for adding the position for each one. You can use something like:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/csv quoteValues=true,header=false,separator="|"
var batchSize = 5
---
payload map ({
    counter: batchSize * (vars.counter - 1) + ($$ + 1)
} ++ $
)
```

Or if you prefer to use the `update` function (this will add the record counter at the last column instead though):

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/csv quoteValues=true,header=false,separator="|"
var batchSize = 5
---
payload map (
    $ update {
        case .counter! -> batchSize * (vars.counter - 1) + ($$ + 1)
    }
)
```

Remember to replace the `batchSize` variable from this code with the same value you're using in the ForEach scope (if it's parameterised, it would be better).

Edit 1 -
Clarification: the `- 1` and `+ 1` are because both indexes (the counter from the `For Each` scope and the `$$` from the `map`) are zero-based.

Answer (score 1):

Just another workaround and to simplify without using any external variables. The script can be split into two; 1st is for Error group and 2nd is for Success.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/csv quoteValues=true,header=false,separator="|"
// Will be used for creating a counter for Error group
var errorIdx = 1  
 // Will be used for creating a counter for Success group
var successIdx = 6
---
//errorItems for the first 5 rows
(payload[0 to 4] map (items,idx) -> (({"0":(idx) + errorIdx} ++ items))) 

++

//successItems from 6 and remaining items.
(payload[5 to -1] map (items,idx) -> (({"0":(idx) + successIdx} ++ items)))
```

**DataWeave Inline Variables:**

- **`errorIdx`** is a pointer for starting the error counter
- **`successIdx`** is a pointer for starting the success counter

*This will extract from index 0 to 4 element:*

```json
payload[0 to 4]
```

*This will extract from index 5 to remaining elements:*

```json
payload[5 to -1]
```